# Bootstrap table pagination and search aren't working when I fetch the data using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm creating a small project using PHP, MySQL, Ajax and Bootstrap. When I fetch the data using PHP include and put in inside table body tag, Bootstrap table pagination and search are working fine, but when I fetch the data using AJAX and append it to the table body using ID the pagination and search aren't working.

The bootstrap pagination and search are working to this code:

```
<!-- Table -->
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
  <div class="card-header py-3">
    <center>
      <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">LIST OF STOCKS</h6>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ASSET TAGS</th>
            <th>PARTICULARS</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <th>PREVIOUS USER</th>
            <th>OPTION</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>ASSET TAGS</th>
            <th>PARTICULARS</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <th>PREVIOUS USER</th>
            <th>OPTION</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody><?php include('../functions/stocks_fetch.php'); ?></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Table -->

// Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable();
});
```

And not working to this code:

```
<!-- Table -->
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
  <div class="card-header py-3">
    <center>
      <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">LIST OF STOCKS</h6>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ASSET TAGS</th>
            <th>PARTICULARS</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <th>PREVIOUS USER</th>
            <th>OPTION</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>ASSET TAGS</th>
            <th>PARTICULARS</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <th>PREVIOUS USER</th>
            <th>OPTION</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Table -->

//FETCH DATA TO DISPLAY
function fetch(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'functions/stocks_fetch.php',
        success: function(response){
            $('#tbody').html(response);
        }
    });
}

<!-- MY NEW WORKING AJAX CODE -->

/FETCH DATA TO DISPLAY
function fetch(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'functions/stocks_fetch.php',
        success: function(response){
            $('#tblbody').html(response);

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#dataTable').DataTable();
              });       
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you really referencing 2 different elements in each example? In the first one you are referencing to `#dataTable` element, while on the second you are referencing to `#tbody`

Comment: Can you show also the code of stocks_fetch.php ??

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply I already solve my problem, I found out that my mistake is I put my Script calling the Bootstrap Plugins in a wrong place which is in the page where is the table stocks is placed. I made some modification with my Ajax code and place the script there after the success response. Now it is working perfectly.